# kafka-connect-bigquery: Regex based syntax in "topics"

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

so I use `kafka-connect-bigquery` [connector](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-bigquery)

Is it possible to use regular expression in "topics"?

For example I have two topics:

```
mysql.database.table1
mysql.database.table2
```

and I want to add it to connector at once:

```
"topics": "mysql.database.*"
```

thanks

Comment: Have you tried "topics.regex":"mysql.database.*" ?

Comment: Yep, it works :) Could you please post it as answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can whitelist Kafka topics based regex by replacing the `topics` property with `topics.regex`.

### Ex.

```
"topics.regex":"mysql.database.*"
```

Comment: Hey! I would like to add another OR operation in my regex but I could not. Could you help me?

`topics.regex: "mysql\\.database\\.(.*)"` works OK but I also want to consume `postgres.db.*`

I've tried:
`topics.regex: "mysql\\.database\\.(.*)|postgres\\.db\\.(.*)"` but no luck. It still only consumes mysql.database

Comment: Hi @ozgenbaris your regex is wrong, it will looks for  \ before `.`  you should replace your regex with   `"mysql.database.(.*)|postgres.db.(.*)"`